# How to remove Ubuntu entry from EFI and/or reinstall OpenBSD boot loader?

Tags: linux, bootloader, openbsd

I have a ThinkPad E15 gen 2 AMD laptop.  It has the stock Toshiba NVMe SSD and an Intel Optane NVMe SSD.  NVMe0 is a spare drive and NVMe1 is the OpenBSD drive.

I had to do something with a disk archive that I couldn't do with OpenBSD so I installed Mint to NVMe0 once done I wiped the disk and thought I would be golden.  That was not so.

Now every time I reboot my laptop I get a grub prompt with no entries.  I checked the UEFI BIOS and there is an entry for Ubuntu in there.  I've instructed the BIOS to lower the priority of this Ubuntu entry, delete it, to no avail.

I want to know how to restore the OpenBSD boot loader and remove the Ubuntu issue for good.

Comment: You actually have to select the entry for the OS you want to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this trying to solve the same problem here is what I did that fixed it:

How I fixed it: Boot into shell, cd to /dev, chmod +x MAKEDEV, ./MAKEDEV SD0, SD1, SD2, SD3 , bioctl -c C -l sd2a , exit, choose the upgrade option, choose sd3 for the root disk, go through the install process, reboot at the end and everything worked and my /usr/local was intact and everything!

Comment: It should be noted that no one needs to delete .efi entries. You can if you want, this works, there are much simpler ways, and you really don't need to delete anything. Installing OpenBSD install it's bootloader and that can be selected from UEFI settings > Boot menu as any other UEFI compatible OS.